# Complex analysis, residues of function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing, residue-calculus

> If $f(z)$ has residue $b_1$ at $z=z_0$, show by example that
>   $[f(z)]^2$ need not to have residue $b_1^2$ at $z=z_0$

What I tried

Suppose that $f$ is analytics in the neighborhood of $z_0$ and that $\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z)=b_1\neq 0$, then $f$ have simple pole at $z_0$ and $\operatorname{Res}(f;z_0)=b_1$.

Now I don't know if I can assume that $\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z)^2=b_2\neq b_1\Rightarrow \operatorname{Res}(f;z_0)\neq \operatorname{Res}(f^2;z_0)$

In the answer they said let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ but I don't know how to proof.

Comment: $f(z) = 1/z$ and $f(z)^{2} = 1/z^{2}$ are their own Laurent expansions. It is easy to read off their residues and see that this is an example.

Comment: @Echan But there is a way to make a general statement, valid for any function?

Comment: I don't understand. It is valid that for an arbitrary $f$ with residue $b_{1}$ at $z=z_{0}$, $f(z)^{2}$ need not have residue $b_{1}^{2}$ at $z=z_{0}$. It is proven by considering $f(z) = 1/z$. What more do you want?

Comment: A single counter example is a valid way to disprove a generalization for every function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_n (z-z_0)^n $$

so that

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z) = b_{-1} $$

Then

$$f(z)^2 = \left [ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_n (z-z_0)^n\right ]^2 = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} a_m (z-z_0)^m$$

where

$$a_m = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_n b_{m-n} $$

Specifically,

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z)^2 = a_{-1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} b_n b_{-(n+1)} $$

As an example, if all $b_n=0$ when $n \lt -1$, then

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z)^2 = 2 b_0 b_{-1} $$